# Alternative to template_from_string for processing strings with calls to custom Twig functions

Tags: php, twig

Is there an alternative to using `template_from_string()` for evaluating strings that contain calls to custom Twig functions (or any other complex Twig code for that matter)?

This is a simplified version of the code I have right now.

```
{% set content = {
    'item_1' : {
        'images' : {
            'src': 'assets/images/img_1-600.jpg',
            'srcset': "{{ assets('assets/images/img_1-600.jpg') }} 600w, {{ assets('assets/images/img_1-1200.jpg') }} 1200w",
        }
    }
    # additional items follow
}

{% for data in content %}
    <img src="{{ data.images.src }}" srcset="{{ include(template_from_string(data.images.srcset)) }}" alt="">
{% endfor %}
```

The `assets()` function simply returns a revisioned version of the static asset for the given path (i.e. `assets('assets/images/img_1-600.jpg)` renders as something like `'assets/images/img_1-600-a4c2254a6d.jpg)`.

The problems start with `img srcset` attribute which can become pretty complex and usually contains references to multiple assets that need to return revisioned values for static assets.

Now I know that I could modify the `assets()` function to support that kind of complex scenario but I'd like to keep things simple and let `assets()` only handle 1:1 transformations.

The only way to achieve this by using functionality provided by Twig seems to be [template_from_string()](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/functions/template_from_string.html) combined with include, which in itself is not terrible but it does kind of look bulky for a simple operation as evaluating and rendering a string.

Not to mention that `template_from_string` requires `StringLoaderExtension()` to be loaded by default, which again I'd like to avoid using for performance reasons.

Comment: @DarkBee That certainly is an option but with most srcset attributes containing at least four image sets I am not sure it wouldn't qucikly become quite unwieldly to maintain such code. However, it does get rid of the additional extension as a dependency so I might actually reconsider about using it. Please add your comment as an aswer in order for me to award you points. Thank you.

Comment: Is your `srcset` static in the file or dynamically generated? If that latter, I'd probably just create a twig function/extension that takes an ID or base image and returns the value or entire attribute.

Comment: Unsure on how to create a more "maintable" solution though, perhaps sthing like creating a twig function that receives an array and chains the assets function in there? `'srcset': srcset({ 600 : 'path/to/600/asset.jpg', 1200 : 'path/to/1200/asset.jpg', }),`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the concatenation approach is not a bad idea, after much consideration I came to the conclusion that this is one of those places where having a custom Twig function makes much more sense.

The main argument in favor of using a function compared to simple concatenation is that with a function there is no need to worry about properly formating the template code (i.e. forget a space between the asset and the size descriptor in the `srcset` attribute value).

This approach also completely eliminates any need to use `template_from_string()` or additional extension dependencies.

Here is the final solution.

The template code, plain and simple, with plenty of overview.

```
{% set content = {
    'item_1' : {
        'images' : {
            'src': 'assets/images/img-600.jpg',
            'srcset': srcset([
                [ assets('assets/images/img-600.jpg'), '600w' ],
                [ assets('assets/images/img-800.jpg'), '800w' ],
                [ assets('assets/images/img-1000.jpg'), '1000w' ],
                [ assets('assets/images/img-1200.jpg'), '1200w' ]
            ]),
        }
    }
    # additional items follow
}

{% for data in content %}
    <img src="{{ data.images.src }}" srcset="{{ data.images.srcset }}" alt="">
{% endfor %}
```

The actual Twig function called `srcset`, that is used to generate a value for the `srcset` attribute from provided data in the above template.

```
public function srcset(array $srcset)
{
    $output = [];
    foreach ($srcset as $set) {
        // Both parameters need to exist or the set isn't added to the output...
        if (!(isset($set[0]) && isset($set[1]))) {
            // ... just some exception handling that isn't of relevance for the question
            // ...
            continue;
        }
        $output[] = sprintf('%s %s', $set[0], $set[1]);
    }

    return implode(', ', $output);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid any extra plugins, you could just concat the variables

```html
{% set content = {
    'item_1' : {
        'images' : {
            'src': 'assets/images/img_1-600.jpg',
            'srcset': assets('assets/images/img_1-600.jpg')~'  600w,'~assets('assets/images/img_1-1200.jpg')~' 1200w',
        }
    }
} %}
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. I will now mark my answer as the accepted one but not because of the points, about which I couldn't care less, but becasue I feel that my answer covers several other details in my question. I hope you don't mind. Cheers.

Comment: No worries, good thing U've swapped out to a custom function, makes it more maintable anyway :)